# Perform Jquery function on multiple divs without user event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a variable called "widthz" that determines the css width for .progress

Each instance of "widthz" is unique since it's determined from the contents other "brother" divs to .progress. Right now, my function works perfectly but only if you click on .item. I want this action to take place for every instance of .progress without a user event such as a click.

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 $( ".budgets .item" ).click(function() {

        var limitz = $(this).children('.limit').html();
        var spentz = $(this).children('.spent').html();
        var widthz = spentz / limitz * 100 ;

        $(this).find('.progress').css('width', widthz + '%');

});




});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the event handler with `each` to iterate over all of them and keep the `this` reference

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".budgets .item" ).each(function() {
        var limitz = $(this).children('.limit').html();
        var spentz = $(this).children('.spent').html();
        var widthz = spentz / limitz * 100 ;

        $(this).find('.progress').css('width', widthz + '%');
    });
});
```

Comment: you are answering tooooooooo fast!

Comment: I thought I'll get this one, and your answer came up.

Comment: @AmitJoki - I'm really a slow typer, but fast copy/paste'er. You'll get it next time!